# Hide REST and Websockets inside the same function using a listener callback for both

Tags: javascript, function, websocket, api-design, signature

I am working on a project with 2 clients, 1 in React Native and 1 in React. There is a common API module, which is auto-generated by an OpenAPI specification, and a Services module that is responsible for calling the API methods and translating the DTOs to a more suitable format.

The app has real-time requirements and fetching is carried out in the following manner:

Let R be a resource on the server with a structure like `{ ...fields..., timestamp: 12345678 }`.
Let N be the timestamp of now. The client apps need to fetch all the R resources that have a timestamp higher than `N - 10 hours` and also subscribe to get new R items, when and if any are created (through Websockets). If the user of the app is currently on a screen that only concerns old data (`N - 10 hours <= timestamp <= N`), then the Websocket subscription should be omitted.

My question is, how bad would it be if I implemented methods like the following where I completely disregard returning Promises, like when someone uses `fetch`, and I use callbacks to inform the user of the method that the "Promise resolved"?

```js
type R = {
  timestamp: Date
}

type API = {
  getR: (start: Date, end: Date) => R[];
  subscribeToR: (onNewR: (r: R) => void) => void;
}

class NewServices {
  constructor(private readonly api: API) {}

  // notice that end is optional and onNewR receives an array
  getR(onNewR: (r: R[]) => void, start: Date, end?: Date): void {
    if (end !== undefined) {
      this.api.getR(start, end).then((resp) => {
        onNewR(resp.data);
      });
      return;
    }

    // end is undefined here
    const lEnd = new Date(); // now
    this.api.getR(start, lEnd).then((resp) => {
      onNewR(resp.data);
      this.api.subscribeToR((r) => onNewR([r]));
    });
  }
}

// The current state of the services
class OldServices {
  constructor(private readonly api: API) {}

  // This class is an example, IRL it does DTO conversions, too

  async getR(start: Date, end: Date): Promise<R[]> {
    return (await this.api.getR(start, end)).data;
  }

  subscribeToR(onNewR: (r: R) => void): void {
    this.api.subscribeToR(onNewR);
  }
}
```

The apparent drawback is that I can no longer use React Query, which I liked.
However, I got tired of writing the `if (end !== undefined)` logic in the (thankfully reusable) business layer of my app and, also, I believe that this "either REST or Websocket" behavior should be abstracted out from the rest of the app and be hidden inside the Services layer, even though it feels like an anti-pattern. What do you suggest/think?